# How to mark maven plugin threadSafe

Tags: maven-3

I want to mark `maven-clean-plugin` as threadsafe using `@threadSafe` annotation. could anybody give an example?

**EDIT:**

After I upgraded to maven 3.0.5, my build got below warnings: (building using teamcity)

```
[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] *****************************************************************Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] * contains the following plugin(s) that are not marked as       *Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] * @threadSafe to support parallel building.                     *Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] * question, not against maven-core                              *Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] *****************************************************************Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in STRAW Main Application:Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.2Agent time: 14:21:10

[18:51:10][com.dir.hay.straw:straw-parent] [WARNING] *****************************************************************
```

From the maven documentation, I too understand that clean plugin is thread safe. Even then, I get this warning. So, I thought I miss something somewhere.

Comment: What would you like to do? The clean plugin is already thread safe (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html). Which version of maven-clean-plugin do you use?

Comment: I didn't read it carefully enough. You are using extreme old versions of plugins maven-clean-plugin 2.3, maven-install-plugin 2.2 etc. you should update the definition of your plugins.

Answer (score 4):

First why you are trying to use is an old style XDoclet annotation which is deprecated you should [Java 5 annotations like this](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html#Supported_Annotations):

What would you like to do? The [maven-clean-plugin is already thread safe](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html). Which version of maven-clean-plugin do you use?

```java
@Mojo( name = "WhatEver",
       threadSafe = true)
public class MyMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
```

Comment: Yes, it was done since version 2.4.1 (may 2010). -> http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCLEAN-43